How to fix this error "Incorrect data types or column count mismatch when inserting rows" in GridDB
Cause: Incorrect data types or column count mismatch when inserting rows.
Solution:

Verify that the row data matches the container schema.
For Blob type, ensure the binary data is passed as a bytearray or bytes.

Example:
row = [
    "unique_id_1",  # id (STRING)
    "example.jpg",  # file_name (STRING)
    "image/jpeg",   # file_type (STRING)
    len(file_data), # file_size (INTEGER)
    file_data       # data (BLOB)
]
container.put(row)

I would like to fix this error as soon as possible.
Thanks.
